# Overload "new" for stl container?

Tags: c++, overloading

Say I have a `std::unorderd_map<U,T>` where U,T are concrete types. Then I'd like that map to use a custom `new` operator just for `std::pair<U,T>` so that everytime I insert something in the map the custom new operator is used. Can that be done? Any hint on how this is possible? I searched for overloading `new` on any stl container but I did not find a whole lot on that topic.

Comment: First thing first, can you clarify whether you know `operator new` and the `new` keyword in `pointer = new SomeType(argument)` are different things?

Comment: I looked it up now and no I wasn't aware of that. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: Glad you notice that. The second thing: I support Kerrek's answer, using custom allocator is a better idea. That is exactly the customization mechanism provided by the standard containers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Forget about overloading any `operator new`. That's a mostly useless language feature. Memory allocation is better done in library than in the core language, and what you should really do is pass your own, custom allocator to your map:

```
MyCustomAllocator<std::pair<const U, T>> alloc(a, b, c);

std::unordered_map<U, T, std::hash<U>, std::equal<U>,
                   MyCustomAllocator<std::pair<const U, T>>> m(10, alloc);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'd say it's really done any better (allocators are a mess) but it's certainly done *differently*, anyway.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I'm not saying that the actual allocators in the standard library are any good, just that memory allocation is a library issue, not a core issue. You don't need to look any further than `std::vector<int>` and realize that it's not using `new int[n]`.

Comment: Could you include a short introduction about how to make the `MyCustomAllocator`? Making custom allocator without some guidance can really be a mess.

Comment: @NickyC: There's a [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_allocator), and maybe [this blog post](http://isocpp.org/blog/2014/08/a-visitors-guide-to-allocators)...

Comment: @JerryCoffin What do you mean with "mess"? Is it a mess implementation-wise or is there a performance downside? Or both?

Comment: Can be both, but mostly implementation-wise (though they did recently add some framework, so you can usually write a fairly efficiently allocator pretty easily).

Comment: Can we actually answer the technical questions instead of proposing alternatives?